# Count calls to eval

Tags: javascript, eval, overriding

I would like to count the number of calls made to eval in our javascript application.

I came up with the following, but it generates errors. These errors are hard to track, and my knowledge of the app is limited.

Can you tell what is wrong with my code ?

```
increment = function (){
  var me = arguments.callee;
  if (!me.count) me.count = 0;
  return ++me.count;
}

var oldEval = eval;

eval = function eval(string){       
  console.log('eval number ', increment());
  return oldEval(string);
}
```

Or to you know an alternative way to count the use of eval ?

thanks

Olivier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a rudimentary solution. It seems to work, at least I can gather some data, but I"m not 100% sure it is correct.

so I just do :

```
eval = eval;
```

With that, firebug's profiler is able to count the calls to eval, but does not group that counting, therefore I have to copy and paste to excel, and build a pivot Table in order to get the data.

Comment: Say What now? Please elaborate!

Comment: There is not much to elaborate.
eval = eval;
after that the calls to eval() are reported by the firebug profiler.

However they are counted on multiple lines, so I use excel to sum them all.

The firebug's profiler output look like that:

eval() 1 0.01% 0.024ms 0.979ms 0.979ms 0.979ms 0.979ms 
326 (line 1)
eval() 1 0.01% 0.024ms 0.991ms 0.991ms 0.991ms 0.991ms 
318 (line 1)
eval() 1 0.01% 0.024ms 0.759ms 0.759ms 0.759ms 0.759ms 
313 (line 1)

This technique can probably by used to count the calls to any other native javascript functions.

Comment: @Olivvv how could i include this in javascript, i mean i am unable to show the parameters of eval with this function

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is not a watertight way of emulating/wrapping eval, because it isn't a normal function. It can access (both read and write) the local variables of the direct caller.

```
function testeval() {
    var a= 2;
    eval('a*= 2');
    alert(a); // 4
};
```

This is magic you can't emulate from a native JavaScript function. You'd have no way from myWrappedEval to get the value of `a` in the caller or write back the changed value. Whilst you can get hold of the caller function using `arguments.caller`, there's no way to read the locals of the function invocation.

You'll have to manually insert a call to `increment` just before each usage of `eval` you can find in the source. Or, better, remove every call to `eval` and replace it with better code, making the call total zero. ;-)

Comment: Forgot about that. Depending on what `eval` is being used for this decorating will probably break it altogether. Damn, JS needs `caller.locals()` so badly.

Comment: Thanks. 
The issue is not related to the increment thing, if I remove it, its the same.
I'm not sure that the arguments.caller question is the origin of the issue, since it breaks on methods that are not making use of that.

Comment: `arguments.caller` is not related to the problem, merely mentioned as a strategy for a workaround (that won't work!). The problem will happen for *any* `eval` call that uses a function's local variables.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that jumps out is your argument name "string"

Try changing it to "str" or something. Some browsers might not like "String" since it is actually a Class name (esp. IE that often ignores case sensitivity sometimes)

Note I tested your code, and it works in Firefox 3.5 (with the Firebug addon installed)

If you don't have a `console` object defined, or a `log` method on said console object - you will get errors. (e.g. if Firebug or similar is not installed)

Answer (score -1):

Try this modified version

```
var increment = function () {
  var me = arguments.callee;
  if (!me.count) me.count = 0;
  return ++me.count;
}

var oldEval = eval;

eval = function (str) {
  alert('eval number ' + increment());
  return oldEval(str);
}
```

- Renamed `string` to `str`
- used alert instead of `console.log` (which isn't available in all browser)
- Changed call to alert to use string concatenation
- changed new eval function to  be anonymous (removed eval name)

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't help. points 1 and 4 are not changing anything and I have hundreds of occurrences  so I won't use alert();

Comment: Ok then replace `alert` again with console.log. So now I assume console.log works for you. Did you consider logging the argument (str) itself and check one which ones it breaks. Then post some samples in your question